# Sum of Scaled Harmonic Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

I came across the following identity:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=1.
$$
However, I do not know how to prove it except verify it by numerical calculations.
Does any one know how to prove it or give me some hints? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the double sum
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$
each fraction $1/k$ occurs $k$ times, so overall these contribute $1$ to the sum.
As $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$, the total sum is $n$.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) can simplify the changing of the order of summation:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\frac1k
&=\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n[k\ge j]\frac1k\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n[k\ge j]\frac1k\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k\frac1k\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n1\\[9pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for mentioning Iverson Brackets of which I was not aware. For some time I was looking for a mathematics symbol for the Mathematica command Boole[].

Answer (score 3):

We can also write the index region conveniently to better see what's going on.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\frac{1}{k}&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq j\leq k\leq n}}\frac{1}{k}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{k}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n1\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Tony: You're welcome.

Comment: (+1) That is pretty much what I was trying to do with the Iverson Brackets.

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks for the credit.

Comment: Your way of viewing this might be clearer to some. That makes it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof uses the well-known formula for the sum of harmonic numbers

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} H_k = (n+1)H_n -n$$

The double sum of the OP can be written as

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left (H_n - H_{j-1}\right)\\
=H_n - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} H_m\\
= H_n - \frac{1}{n} \left (n H_{n-1} -n +1\right)\\
= H_n - H_{n-1} + 1 -\frac{1}{n} = 1$$

In the second line we have used that $H_0=0$, and in last line we have employed the defining recursion relation of the harmonic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

By double counting we have

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{k}=\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^{n}1=\frac1n \cdot n=1$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Tony You are welcome. As you can see, reversing the counting method, it becomes trivial.

Comment: IMHO this is the most enlighting method to show what is going on in double sums.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I totally agree with you! :)